# .NET Maui App same DisplayAlert showing up multiple times on the same page

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, mobile, maui

I have a helper class that displays some alerts like this:

```
[...] // other code
 
public class Alerts{
    public Alerts() {}
    public async Task AlertMessage(){
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(mymessages);
    }
}

[...] // other code
```

I got a viewmodel binded with a view which is a sub-page meaning that I have to perform some navigation to see this view/sub-page, this one consumes this alert after a certain event is triggered.

In the viewmodel I have instantiated the Alerts class and called the AlertMessage method

```
[...] // other code

public Alerts Alert = new Alerts();
await Alert.AlertMessage();

[...] // other code
```

**My issue is that** when the app starts and I go to that page and that event is triggered the alert is shown only 1 time (as it should of course) but when I go back to other pages and then come back to this specific page where the alert is shown, the alert is shown more than once one stacked on top of the other. **I noticed that the number of the alerts shown on that page is the same number of the navigation I have performed**: so if I went back and fort on that page 2 times I got 2 alerts one on top of the other, 3 times back and forth 3 alerts ect.. Only the first time the alert is shown once infact that is the 1st time I navigate to that page.

Comment: When and where is it that you call `AlertMessage()`? Please provide more context for the code. Do you, by any chance, make the call in an event handler (you're writing *"that event is triggered"*)?

Comment: Did you use the `OnAppearing()` method in the code behind?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT nope...how should I use it?

Comment: You can override the OnAppearing() method like this in your code behind.           `public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

    }

}`

Comment: Here is the information about the [OnAppearing() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.onappearing?view=net-maui-8.0) you can refer to.